# How to split data into train,test and validation sets?

Tags: python

Following is my code:
Here is the main function

```
trainingSet=[]
    testSet=[]
    validationSet=[]

    loadDataset('iris.data.txt', trainingSet, testSet,validationSet)
```

And this is the loadDataset function

```
def loadDataset(filename,  trainingSet=[] ,testSet=[],validationSet=[]):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
        lines = csv.reader(csvfile)
        dataset = list(lines)
        for x in range(len(dataset)-1):
            for y in range(4):
                dataset[x][y] = float(dataset[x][y])
            random.shuffle(dataset)


        trainingSet .append(dataset[:106])
        testSet.append(dataset[106:128])
        validationSet.append(dataset[128:150])
```

"loadDataset gets wine data set csv and converts it into a list of floats. Then it splits the data."

I am trying to split my data into 70-15-15. But when I print the lengths of each list it gives 1.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) applies here.  We cannot effectively help you until you post your MCVE code and accurately describe the problem.
We should be able to paste your posted code into a text file and reproduce the problem you described.  In particular, hard-code a sample data set, and print the data as they're loaded (by the function).

Comment: You probably need `trainingSet.extend(dataset[:106])`. A few `print` statements can help you figure out what's going on. E. g. `print trainingSet` and `print len(trainingSet[0])`. These print statements are for Python 2.7 -- If you're on Python 3.x, you need extra parantheses, like so: `print(trainingSet)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply using `.extend` instead of `.append` should solve your issue. `.append` adds the slice `dataset[xxx]` as a single element to the list. `.extend`, on the other hand, adds all the elements in `dataset[xxx]` to the list.

However, if you only call `loadDataSet` once, as in your example, there is no need to initialize empty datasets, and you can return the ranges directly.

main function:

```
trainingSet, testSet, validationSet = loadDataset('iris.data.txt')
```

loadDataset function:

```
def loadDataset(filename):
    with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
        lines = csv.reader(csvfile)
        dataset = list(lines)
        for x in range(len(dataset)-1):
            for y in range(4):
                dataset[x][y] = float(dataset[x][y])
            random.shuffle(dataset)


        trainingSet = dataset[:106]
        testSet = dataset[106:128]
        validationSet = dataset[128:150]
        return trainingSet, testSet, validationSet
```